# Connecting two HDMI screen to laptop via type C port using USB hub

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi, usb-hub, usb-3.1-type-c

Connecting two (USB 3.0 to HDMI adapter) to (Type C to 4 Port USB 3.0 HUB) and connecting the type c to my HP laptop windows 10 will works in order to connect two HDMI screen ?

example of hardware:

- Type C to 4 Port USB 3.0 HUB (https://www.aliexpress.com/item/USB-C-3-1-Type-C-to-4-Port-USB-3-0-HUB-Adapter-For-Apple/32710545605.html)
- USB 3.0 to HDMI Output (https://www.aliexpress.com/item/5Gbps-Input-USB-3-0-to-HDMI-Output-Graphic-Adapter-1080P-Cable-Converter-for-MAC-HDTV/32825312669.html)

Comment: You want to connect monitors that I assume are more than $200 to $12 worth of plastic?  Type-C cables **are not created equal**.  Many do not conform to the standard.  I am very suspect of those adapters.  I would go for quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, two USB3 to HDMI adapters (or more) should work fine behind a good USB 3.0 hub, provided that the USB driver for the video interface allows multiple instances of the device.

The particular USB3 to HDMI adapter is listed as having 300 mA power consumption, so the "my HP laptop's" Type-C port should be able to handle the power for two adapters (600 mA) plus hub itself (~ 100-200 mA), about 700 - 800 mA total, which is well within the basic USB 3.0 power requirement.

The hub, however, has a suspicious statement, "Certification : Does not apply" . So it is possible that something is fairly wrong with this hub, and some devices might not work.